# Find the total mass of a spherical film.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Could anyone help me propose the surface integral, to solve this problem extracted from the book "Calculus of vector functions, page 369"?

Find the total mass of a spherical film having density at each point equal to the linear distance of the point from a single fixed point on the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Since the point is arbitrary, you might as well make it the south pole:
$$\rho(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z+r)^2}.$$

Now use the fact that $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ and get
$$\rho(x,y,z) = \sqrt{2r^2 + 2 r z}.$$

Then you are trying to calculate
$$\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2} \rho(x,y,z)\,dA.$$
Notice that $\rho$ depends only on $z$, which might suggest a particularly useful coordinate system to choose when performing this calculation.
Can you take it from here?